# Firefox built-in PDF viewer stopped working recently?

Tags: firefox, pdf

Previously my Firefox on Ubuntu would open PDF documents in the built-in Firefox PDF viewer fine. I noticed recently that this behaviour had changed and now when I click on a PDF it tries to do a download. This is same web site, same PDF as worked before.

I am not sure if this is a Firefox issue or a Ubuntu issue or a bit of both. Anyone else have this issue?

I am currently running Firefox 77.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have this same bug/behaviour on two different PCs.

I have only seen very (years) old posts on this subject, nothing recently. I have already tried:

- Changing the Firefox PDF setting from "Open in Firefox" to "Use system default application" which DOES do the expected behaviour (opens in Envince) but changing the setting back does NOT open in Firefox.
- Checking firefox pdfjs.disabled setting (it's false).
- Disabling all add-ons.
- Looked for answers on Mozilla site such as [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=view-pdf-files-firefox#w_troubleshoot-problems-with-the-pdf-viewer)

Comment: I published this bug on launchpad as [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1908049](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1908049)